# List value changes while i'm not using it in the function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to divide and a dataset to an uncertain and certain value. I've made different functions for those purposes, but when I call the function to make value uncertain, the certain value changed too. Heres what it looks like:

I read a few answered question and they say that I need to make a copy of my list, I did, but the problem still occurs.

```py
def loadCertainDataset(a, b, dataset=[], dataset1=[], trainCe=[], testCe=[]):
    temp=dataset[:]
    temp1=dataset1[:]
    for x in range(0,a):
        for y in range(4):
            temp[x][y]=float(temp[x][y])
        trainCe.append(temp[x])
    for x in range(0,b):
        for y in range(4):
            temp1[x][y]=float(temp1[x][y])
        testCe.append(temp1[x])

def loadUncertainDataset(a,b,dataset=[],dataset1=[],trainUn=[],testUn=[]):
    temp=dataset[:]
    temp1=dataset1[:]
    c=0
    for x in range(a,len(dataset)):
        for y in range(4):
            d=float(temp[c][y])
            temp[c][y]=uniformProb(5,d,5)
        trainUn.append(temp[c])
        c+=1
    c=0
    for x in range(b,len(temp1)):
        for y in range(4):
            d=float(temp1[c][y])
            temp1[c][y]=uniformProb(5,d,5)
        testUn.append(temp1[c])
        c+=1

def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            if random.random() < split:
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
            else:
                testSet.append(dataset[x])

def main():
    trainingSet=[]
    trainCe=[]
    testSet=[]
    testCe=[]
    split = 0.67
    # loading dataset
    loadDataset('iris.data', split, trainingSet, testSet)
    n=len(trainingSet)/2
    m=len(testSet)/2
    #split first half for certain dataset
    loadCertainDataset(n,m,trainingSet,testSet,trainCe,testCe)
    trainUn=[]
    testUn=[]
    #other half for uncertain dataset
    loadUncertainDataset(n,m,trainingSet,testSet,trainUn,testCe
    print(testCe)

main()
```

I expected output for `print(testCe)` as a 2-dimensional array

```
> [6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3, 'Iris-virginica']
```

but what I get is 3-dimensional array

```
> [array([9.6913696 , 9.36996183, 7.5334876 , 6.80333322, 7.3538702 ]),
> array([5.32638532, 7.3171699 , 4.49632398, 3.86691709, 7.90622172]),
> array([6.89951614, 7.58021047, 7.5585632 , 8.85561941, 5.47507325]),
> array([5.3910737 , 5.0039284 , 1.97381302, 6.51333703, 4.07850765]),
> 'Iris-versicolor'], [array([ 6.85037363,  7.67665646,  8.09445476, 
> 6.24119721, 10.67032386]), array([4.46818369, 7.66358385, 4.24088535, 6.71903264, 7.6154301 ]), array([7.1805261 , 8.75463451, 8.98668969, 9.24723654, 4.85404661]), array([4.58140956, 1.5211153 , 3.72896749, 4.63736249, 4.26095836]), 'Iris-versicolor']
```

The 3-dimensional array is supposed to be an uncertain dataset, but `testCe` is supposed to be certain (2-dimensional array). when I don't call

```
> loadUncertainDataset(...)
```

`print(testCe)` would return 2-dimensional arrays. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, lists and dictionaries are mutable. That means

```
def myfunc(a=[]):
    a.append(0)
    print(a)

myfunc()
myfunc()
myfunc()
```

will print

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

because the `a` is always pointing to the same list.

What you need to do here is:

```
def myfunc(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = []
    a.append(0)
    print(a)
```

This will give you:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

If you do this a lot, you can write a function to automate this:

```
def default_vals(callable, *args):
    return tuple(arg if arg is not None else callable() for arg in args)


def myfunc(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    a, b, c = default_vals(list, a, b, c)
    a.append(0)
    b.append(1)
    c.append(2)
    print(a, b, c)

myfunc()
myfunc()
```

will print

```
[0] [1] [2]
[0] [1] [2]
```

To make it even easier you can probably write some kind of decorator to automate this even more.

Comment: or alternatively you can add copy for `trainCe = trainCe[:]` and `testCe = testCe[:]`

Comment: okay, i can understand if in my code, trainingSet and testSet will change due to its mutable attribute. but i declare trainCe and trainUn as different list, still when i change trainUn, trainCe changed as well

Comment: oh, in function loadCertainDataset() and loadUncertainDataset() i copied the list using slicing method, still the problems occurs

Comment: is it because i still use python-2.7?

Comment: No, that's just how python is designed. The parameters in the function are initialized at the point when the function is initialized, not when the function is called. This is the same in python3.

Comment: sorry, i havent got the time to visit this again. thank you very much, your answer helped me

Comment: use .copy() instead of slicing helped me